# Implicit ODE method via predictor-corrector ad infinitum vs. root solve

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

First of all, I hope you'll forgive me for being a mathematically naïve physicist. I use results and methods from numerical analysis quite a bit, but my formal education in it is a bit lacking. I'll do my best to explain things carefully enough that you can help me find an answer to my question.

A few summers ago during an internship, I was working on a cosmology project that needed us to solve a rather large and complicated set of equations representing a network of chemical reactions. The method of choice was the backward Euler method, which had two desirable features: 1) simplicity, and 2) the ability to integrate stiff equations.

Since backward Euler is implicit, we solved it with a multidimensional Newton's method, resulting in an equation that looked something like
$$(I-J(\mathbf{y}^i_{n+1})\Delta t)(\mathbf{y}^{i}_{n+1}-\mathbf{y}^{i+1}_{n+1})=\mathbf{y}^i_{n+1}-\mathbf{y}_n-F(\mathbf{y}^i_{n+1})\Delta t,$$
where $\mathbf{y}$ is the solution to the differential equation $\frac{d\mathbf{y}}{dt}=F(\mathbf{y})$, lower indices indicate time steps, upper indices indicate Newton solve iterations, $I$ is the identity matrix, $\Delta t$ is the time step, and $J$ is the Jacobian of $F$ with respect to $\mathbf{y}$. We then solved it via Gaussian elimination and repeated until we had the desired accuracy.

This actually worked alright for a while, but as the system of reactions grew, the Jacobian became more and more badly conditioned, thus making the root solve more and more unstable. There's not an immediately obvious structure to the matrix except some possible diagonal dominance, and no one in my group at the time was really familiar with any preconditioning algorithm that might help. This was compounded by the issue that backwards Euler is only first-order accurate, which meant that we often had to perform several substeps in time in order to keep pace with the rest of the cosmology code.

I'm no longer working on that project (or even in that field), but I was recently looking at some applications of predictor-corrector methods in my current field. Most predictor-corrector methods are applied as a series of prediction, evaluation, and correction steps, typically abbreviated as P(EC)$^k$ or P(EC)$^k$E. If these steps are applied until the method converges, it's effectively an implicit method.

So, I started thinking back to my old cosmology project. I can write a simple toy code using the trapezoidal method,
$$\mathbf{y}_{n+1}=\mathbf{y}_n+\frac{1}{2}(f(\mathbf{y}_n,t)+f(\mathbf{y}_{n+1},t+\Delta t))\Delta t,$$
and then solve it by approximating $\mathbf{y}_{n+1}$ with Euler's method and repeatedly applying the above step until it converges. This results in something like the following:
$$\mathbf{y}^{i+1}_{n+1}=\mathbf{y}_n+\frac{1}{2}(f(\mathbf{y}_n,t)+f(\mathbf{y}^i_{n+1},t+\Delta t))\Delta t.$$
It seems to work well in a handful of toy cases, and it demonstrates both the expected 2nd-order convergence and reasonable stability expected from the trapezoidal method. I haven't done a head-to-head comparison, but I expect that it requires more iterations to solve than using Newton's method. That being said, I also don't have to calculate a Jacobian or perform an $\mathcal{O}(n^3)$ linear solve, just a few $\mathcal{O}(n)$ calculations of the right-hand side.

That brings me to my question: other than slower convergence, is there any reason that using this sort of fixed-point iteration is objectively a bad idea compared to calculating a Jacobian and using Newton's method? Will it avoid the issues associated with a poorly conditioned Jacobian matrix? It seems like such a simple idea that I'm led to believe there must be a problem with it because it doesn't seem like it *is* used that often, but I honestly don't have the math chops to validate that one way or another.

EDIT: I should also clarify that I'm aware that the backward Euler method is more stable than the trapezoidal method, but the heart of my question is less about the method for solving the ODE and more about the method for solving an implicit equation.

Comment: The fixed-point iteration has a convergence rate of $Lh$ or $Lh/2$. With the (simplified) Newton method, even if you re-use the Jacobian and the factorization over multiple steps, you get a convergence in the implicit equation with constant $O(h^2)$, which is better for smaller $h$.

Comment: That's very helpful, and it agrees with my expectations. The fixed-point iteration converges linearly, and Newton's method converges quadratically.

However, the Jacobian as used here was often poorly conditioned for many systems, as the chemical abundances of each species often varied over several orders of magnitude. Is fixed-point iteration without explicitly evaluating a Jacobian going to present the same problem, since it's inherently trying to calculate the same vector?

Comment: This appears to be a case for step size control. If $h$ is small enough, $I-\gamma hJ$ becomes regular again.